# Ruby bundle install doesn't match Gemfile.lock: "Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I encountered a weird problem. In the `Gemfile.lock`, it states `json (1.8.6)`.

Basically, I can use `bundle install` to install `json-1.8.6`.

However, it still threw the following error when I run `rspec` command.

```
Could not find json-1.8.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Bundler version `1.15.0`

Ruby `2.3.3`

Comment: did you initially bundle install --path=#####?

Comment: You might want to try RAILS_ENV=test bundle install.

Comment: @MohitSrivastava `RAILS_ENV=test bundle install` didn't work

Comment: @MichaelGorman I am not sure what are you trying to say.

Comment: if you installed the bundle globally, you may have a conflicting gem in another project on your computer.  try running `bundle install --path=vendor`  this will create a local directory where the gems for this project and only this project lives

Comment: I  run the `bundle install --path=vendor`,  but it fails again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ruby source in gemfile should be: `source 'https://rubygems.org'`

or try adding the github path of the gem:

```
gem 'json', :git => 'https://github.com/flori/json.git'
```

Also try doing a `bundle update`.

If none of these work, please post your gemfile.

Comment: I thought it's not about the `gemfile`, because my co-worker shares the same gem file. I notice that the result in `gem list` is  `json (1.8.6, default: 1.8.3)`, maybe the 1.8.3 cause this error.

Comment: did you try `bundle update` then, or try to delete your Gemfile.lock and then do a `bundle install`

Comment: I try, and it both fails.

Comment: Still the same error, I am tying reinstall `rvm` and `ruby` now.

Comment: Magically, after I run the command `rake db:test:prepare`, it fix this problem.

Comment: Coda Chang, Please take a look at    [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/578), I think there may be some issue in Bundle version 1.15.

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar problem recently and couldn't install one of the gems. I am not sure why, but I think it's because of the new Windows update (just a blind shot)

I have managed to repair it with **reinstalling** Ruby and devkit for it.

Good luck!